# Autofac - Property Injection in Action Filter in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control, autofac

While coding an app using **ASP.NET Web API 2** I've managed to achieve **Property Injection** at filter level using **Autofac**.

(the example below belongs to non-core ASP.NET Web API)

```
builder.Register(x => new MyCustomGlobalActionFilter())
    .AsWebApiActionFilterOverrideFor<MyCustomController>()
    .InstancePerRequest()
    .PropertiesAutowired();
```

A couple of things to mention:

- we are supposed to register it for any controller like this: `.AsWebApiActionFilterOverrideFor<MyCustomController>()`
- the following bit is used to enable **Property Injection**: `.PropertiesAutowired()`

The action filter itself looks a bit unusual as long as it's closely related to Autofac - we implement `IAutofacActionFilter` interface.

Then I can resolve services at filter level via property injection, here's code example:

```
public class MyCustomGlobalActionFilter : IAutofacActionFilter
{
    public Session Session { get; set; }
    public DbContextWithUserAuditing DbContext { get; set; }
    public ITenantService TenantService { get; set; }

    public Task OnActionExecutingAsync(
        HttpActionContext actionContext, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken
        )
    {
        string userId = null;
        int? tenantId = null;

        var claimsIdentity = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

        // do some stuff

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task OnActionExecutedAsync(
        HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken
        )
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

So, in order to resolve services as properties we just declare them as follows:

```
public Session Session { get; set; }
public DbContextWithUserAuditing DbContext { get; set; }
public ITenantService TenantService { get; set; }
```

---

My question: **is there a way to resolve services via property injection in a filter using Autofac in `ASP.NET Core`?**

Comment: Have you searched for answers to this or tried anything that didn't work? A quick Google on `asp.net core action filter dependency injection` yields [this blog article](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/dependency-injection-in-action-filters-in-asp.net-core) which suggests you an use the `[ServiceFilter(MyFilterType)]` to push your filter through DI. Registering your type with `PropertiesAutowired` in Autofac would then get you what you want.

Comment: Hi @TravisIllig, thanks for your reply. Tried it with `PropertiesAutowired `, that doesn't resolve properties. See my answer about Dependency Injection below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn't answer my question in fact, still some people might find it useful.

Rather than following **Service Locator** approach, with filter in ASP.NET Core you can pretty much use **Dependency Injection**.

Enjoy!

```
public class MyCustomFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private Session _session;
    private DBContextWithUserAuditing _dbContext;
    private ITenantService _tenantService;

    public MyCustomFilter(
        Session session,
        DBContextWithUserAuditing dbContext,
        ITenantService tenantService
        )
    {
        _session = session;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _tenantService = tenantService;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
        ActionExecutingContext context,
        ActionExecutionDelegate next
        )
    {
        string userId = null;
        int? tenantId = null;

        // do stuff
        // ...

        var resultContext = await next();
    }
}
```

The major dilemma is resolved - we don't use **Service Locator** at least.

IMHO, **Property Injection** isn't very crucial, so I understand why **Autofac** team isn't in a particular rush implementing it.

Comment: If it's not working, it's not because Autofac didn't implement it; it would be due to the way ASP.NET Core resolves it. There's nothing additional for Autofac to implement.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat later answer but maybe it can help others in the future. It's [documented by Autofac](https://docs.autofac.org/en/v7.0.0/integration/mvc.html#enable-property-injection-for-action-filters) how to do this. You will have to declare your dependencies as public properties and call `builder.RegisterFilterProvider();` after registering all your dependencies.